# Is it safe to store the flag in NSUserDefaults once purchase is done via In App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, in-app-purchase

I have some features which would be unlocked only after the purchase through in app purchase.

Is it fine if I store the flag value in NSUserDefaults to check whether app has been purchased or not?

Is it safe to store the flag in NSUserDefaults once purchase is done via In App Purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is the best way. At lease I stored in NSUSerDefault in my Non-Consumable In-app purchase type.. So it is working as charm for me until now.

Comment: How do you prevent someone sharing their NSUserDefaults setting to all users of the app? Or is this file off limits unless you jailbreak?

Comment: @PsychoDad this file is within limits on any device. [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) and [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) let you copy, modify and replace these files. The file NSUserDefaults is written to is located at `[sandbox path]/Library/Preferences/[bundle identifier].plist` (usually bundle identifier is com.company.appname). Please see [Theo’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16762420/178805).

Answer (score 33):

No, this is **not safe**.

The contents NSUserDefaults are stored in plain text. They can be accessed and modified with tools like [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). This also works on devices that are not jailbroken.

This means that if you save the purchase information in the NSUserDefaults, users can unlock your content without doing an actual purchase.

To save the flags in a way that is not as easy to "crack", you could do one of the following:

1. Save an additional salted hash of your stored information. Use the hash to validate that the user has not modified the information. You can find an implementation of this concept [here](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/Secure-NSUserDefaults).
2. Save the flags in the keychain. Read more in Apple's [Keychain Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897). You can find several implementations of this concept on GitHub, e.g. [Lockbox](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox).

**Update:** As of iOS 8.3, the access to the app sandbox is somewhat restricted. While this adds some security, I would still not recommend using NSUserDefaults, as access to the sandbox is still possible for jailbroken devices, apps that have *iTunes file sharing* enabled, and of course devices running older versions of iOS.

Comment: This is the case with [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) also. I was able to edit Letterpress’ NSUserDefaults property list and turn off the sound in my copy. If `customerHasPurchaseApp` was a key one would be able to use it for free.

Comment: Anyone who wants to modify the NSUserDefaults property list file need only edit `[sandbox]/Library/Preferences/[bundle identifier].plist`. For example, Letterpress is `com.atebits.ios.Letterpress.plist`. This is incredibly easy to do with PhoneView (I have not tried iExplorer).

Comment: Would you have same reservations if flag was reset after validating receipt each time app was loaded?

Comment: @Theo: +1 Great answer..!! This is a real value addition to this post. I am sorry that I am very late to reply. Thanks for value addition :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the best way. So you can tract through flag which are stored in NSUserDefault.

But,
When you delete the app from device then it's value become FALSE.
So it will ask for purchase again. But, it will not charge user for purchase same thing again.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination.

Comment: -1. See [Theo’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16762420/178805). Allowing the user to restore their purchase is implemented (for non-consumable purchase) through Store Kit. You have to give the user an option to restore purchases—this is separate from NSUserDefaults.